# Getting "Results have expired, rerun the query if needed." error message when running code in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

I'm encountering the following error message when I attempt to run SQL code in the Hive editor in Hue:

```
Results have expired, rerun the query if needed.
```

So far neither I nor IT can figure out the problem.

Several coworkers have faced similar problems and suggest signing out of Hue, clearing my browser cache and closing the browser, then sign back into Hue. Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.

Has anyone run into this same error? Any suggestions? It's frustrating because I'm pretty much dead in the water in my job until this is fixed.

Comment: So you don't even get results? It just throws that exception?

Comment: @Andrei That's correct, no results - only the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - I've cleared up the "Results have expired, rerun the query if needed." message but I had to clear my browser cache, close the browser **and** shut down my computer & then restart.

Comment: Weird as normally the result expiration is handled via https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/administration/reference/#hive-and-impala-queries-life-cycle which is independent. In any case, glad that the problem is gone!

Comment: I only had to close and restarted firefox